# New variable based on multiple ifelse conditions R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe, `users_full`, in which I would like to create a new variable, `party_followers`, that has the following categories: AFD, SPD, CDU, FDP, Linke, Multiple, or Other.

I would like to create the categories for the new variable by matching `users_full$user_id` to the `user_id` variable of the respective dataframe of followers, e.g., `afd_followers`, `spd_followers`, etc.

The problem is that `users_full$user_id` can be a follower of multiple parties, and I am not sure how to account for this using an ifelse statement.

I tried the following, but it's not working.

```
mutate(users_full, party_followers = ifelse(user_id == afd_followers$user_id & user_id != cdu_followers$user_id & user_id != spd_followers$user_id & user_id != linke_followers$user_id & user_id != fdp_followers$user_id, "AfD",
                                user_id == cdu_followers$user_id & user_id != afd_followers$user_id & user_id != spd_followers$user_id & user_id != linke_followers$user_id & user_id != fdp_followers$user_id, "CDU",
                                user_id == spd_followers$user_id & user_id != cdu_followers$user_id & user_id != afd_followers$user_id & user_id != linke_followers$user_id & user_id != fdp_followers$user_id, "SPD",
                                user_id == linke_followers$user_id & user_id != cdu_followers$user_id & user_id != afd_followers$user_id & user_id != spd_followers$user_id & user_id != fdp_followers$user_id, "Linke",
                                user_id == fdp_followers$user_id & user_id != cdu_followers$user_id & user_id != afd_followers$user_id & user_id != spd_followers$user_id & user_id != linke_followers$user_id, "FDP",
                                user_id == afd_followers$user_id & cdu_followers$user_id & spd_followers$user_id & linke_followers$user_id & fdp_followers$user_id, "Multiple", "Other"))
```

Below, I reconstructed samples of the dataframes I am using.

```
users_full <- data.frame(
user_id = c("3854371132", "883470465498587138", "145216962", "2223089418", 
"2861583057", "271413649"))

spd_followers <- data.frame(
user_id = c("145216962", "3864655101", "757305123165069312", "4854498122", 
"1201495387", "565422099"))


afd_followers <- data.frame(
user_id = c("3854371132", "883470465498587138", "845969869778685952", "3864655101", 
"757305123165069312", "793677341042044928"))

cdu_followers <- data.frame(
user_id = c("3854371132", "145216962", "3864655101", "757305123165069312", 
"3207639056", "4854498122"))

linke_followers <- data.frame(
user_id = c("47289872", "1044855103", "565082298", 
"956148596042330112", "2490464967", "956147739951329280"))
```

I would like to end up with the following output:

```
user_id party_followers
883470465498587000  AfD
3854371132  Multiple
1044855103  Linke
757305123165069000  Multiple
3207639056  SPD
947682953   Other
```

Comment: Your code is a little confusing. Can you please include your expected output?

Comment: I updated with an example of expected output.

Comment: Your use of `==` does row-wise comparisons, where order matters. I think you mean to be using `%in%`, where order wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be scalable without copy/pasting in case you have additional `follower` data frames, I would put all the followers in a `list`, collapse them to a single data frame, and use a `merge`.

Using `data.table`:

```
followers = list(spd = spd_followers, afd = afd_followers, cdu = cdu_followers, linke = linke_followers)
foll = data.table::rbindlist(followers, idcol = "party_followers")

setkey(foll, "user_id")
foll[, user_id := as.character(user_id)]

setDT(users_full, key = "user_id")
users_full[, user_id := as.character(user_id)]

foll[, n := .N, by = user_id]
foll[n > 1, party_followers := "multiple"]
foll = unique(foll)
merge(users_full, foll, all = TRUE)
 #               user_id party_followers  n
 # 1:         1044855103           linke  1
 # 2:         1201495387             spd  1
 # 3:          145216962        multiple  2
 # 4:         2223089418              NA NA
 # 5:         2490464967           linke  1
 # 6:          271413649              NA NA
 # 7:         2861583057              NA NA
 # 8:         3207639056             cdu  1
 ...
```

I'm not sure what `merge` behavior you want. Use `all = TRUE` to include all users in any of the data frames. Use `all.x = TRUE` to restrict to only the users in `users_full`, or `all = FALSE` to do an inner join, only the users that are both in `users_full` and in at least one of the `follower` data frames. I left in the `n` column showing how many networks each user is in - you can remove it if you want.

Comment: This is good but I was not sure if the followers list would be collapsible into a data frame, since although each element of the list has the same length in the example, I did not see why that would have to always be the case.

Comment: @qdread It's a long format, so the number of rows in each `follower` data frame is irrelevant. If there are extraneous columns, they can be easily omitted (or included with the `fill = TRUE` arg in `rbindlist`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional approach using only base R and which can be easily expanded by adding to the list of followers/vector of party names. In the past I'd have used `sapply()` but it is advised to use `vapply()` in functions because the format of its output is more predictable.

```
# Define function to get party name for each user ID
# by checking membership in each party.
get_party <- function(user_id, 
                      id_list = followers_by_party, 
                      id_labels = party_names) {
  in_party <- vapply(id_list, function(x) user_id %in% x$user_id, logical(1))
  if (sum(in_party) == 0) return('Other')
  if (sum(in_party) > 1) return('Multiple')
  return(id_labels[in_party])
}

# create list of user IDs by party and vector of name labels.
followers_by_party <- list(spd_followers, afd_followers, cdu_followers, linke_followers)
party_names <- c('SPD','AfD','CDU','Linke')

# apply this function to each of the user IDs
users_full$party_followers <- vapply(users_full$user_id, get_party, character(1))
```

Comment: Clever solution, though it's too bad it can't be vectorized over `user_id`.

Comment: Yes @Gregor I tried to figure out how to do that but failed :)

Answer (score 0):

Not using ifelse, just vector comparison from base R. The multiple gets checked last, so it overwrites the places that would have other party names.

```
spd <- users_full$user_id %in% spd_followers$user_id
afd <- users_full$user_id %in% afd_followers$user_id
cdu <- users_full$user_id %in% cdu_followers$user_id
linke <- users_full$user_id %in% linke_followers$user_id
multiple <- (afd + cdu + spd + linke) > 1
other <- (afd + cdu + spd + linke) == 0

party_followers <- rep(NA, length(spd))
party_followers[spd] <- "SPD"; party_followers[afd] <- "AFD"
party_followers[cdu] <- "CDU"; party_followers[linke] <- "Linke"
party_followers[multiple] <- "Multiple"; party_followers[other] <- "Other"

users_full$party_followers <- party_followers
```